# What is the the good R2 to compute the effect size (Cohen's f2) in a mixed-effect model

Tags: r, mixed-model, p-value, effect-size

I have a generalized linear model here. Sample size (N=60), implemented with R:

> V = 1+ age + sex + group + random(kinship)

So I did this GLM with r using anova() with LRT test, I also wanted to compute the effect size with Cohen's f2 borrowing the formula from this paper: [Shinichi Nakagawa](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/236002442_A_General_and_Simple_Method_for_Obtaining_R2_from_Generalized_Linear_Mixed-Effects_Models)

But the choice should be made to compute the f2, either using Marginal R2 (only explained by fixed effect) or Conditional R2 (variances explained by both fixed effect and random effect). Personally, I would like to use the conditional R2, because we do have random effect in our model. But the result of f2 and p-value looks a little strange (we are not statisticiens). So to be clear, we defined two models:

> Full model: V1 = 1+ age + sex + group + random(kinship)
>
> Reduced model: V2 = 1+ age + sex + random(kinship)

Then we fit these two models to anova() with LRT test. Also, I use r.squaredGLMM() to compute the two kinds of R2 from these corresponding mixed-effect model V1 and V2.

Here is the result for one comparison:

> f2cohenCondition, f2cohenMarginal,    R2CompletCondition, R2LowContdition,    R2CompletMarginal,  R2LowMarginal,  pvalue, pvalue_mult
>
> 0 0.14    0.596701511 0.595587344 0.185428647 0.074961457 0.002*  0.028*

So my supervisor said that for a small/medium sample size, it is impossible to have 0 effect size, but with a significant p-value (0.028), this happens when the sample size is huge (i.e. 10000). As we can see, the cohen'f2 from 
**f2cohenCondition** and **f2cohenMarginal** tell different stories, and my supervisor thinks **f2cohenMarginal** is more reasonable result.

From this paper: [Gail M. Sullivan](http://www.jgme.org/doi/full/10.4300/JGME-D-12-00156.1)

They verified (I also saw in other papers):

> With a sufficiently large sample, a statistical test will almost always demonstrate a significant difference, unless there is no effect whatsoever, that is, when the effect size is exactly zero; yet very small differences, even if significant, are often meaningless.

So I think in our case, 0 effect size with significant p-value is possible caused by chance, and that is the point why we should report effect size.

Dears statisticiens, please help me to clarify a little :)

Thanks the community in advance

Hao

Comment: Does the significant p-value with nearly 0 effect size means that the significance found was just by chance and it is meaningless?